# Finding how many times values in a vector increased in a row

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to have my program return how many times the values in a vector increased or stayed the same in a row. Is there a simple way of doing this?

An example:

Given vector:

[9 4 5 7 3 2 3 3 4]

Expected result: 3

Since at the end of the vector the value increased or remained the same three times

Another Example:
[3 2 8 1 3 9 9 10 4 5 7 2 ]
Expected result: 4

Comment: Not clear what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mean to count max runs. We can write a function using `rle`.

```
get_max_runs <- function(x) {
  with(rle(diff(x) >= 0), max(lengths[values]))
}

get_max_runs(c(9, 4, 5, 7, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4))
#[1] 3
get_max_runs(c(3, 2, 8, 1, 3, 9, 9, 10, 4, 5, 7, 2))
#[1] 4
```